# How can I pass VM arguments to gradle from command line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

How can I pass VM arguments to gradle from command line. The Gradle Tool option in Idea is working fine ( screehshot attached).
I am trying to pass --add-opens to gradle and am aware of -P but it is not working.

[The GRADLE VM options from the Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUxnr.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GRADLE_OPTS environment variable. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables)

Comment: I tried using : `gradle GRADLE_OPTS="-D--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED" --debug --stacktrace`  and  `gradle GRADLE_OPTS="-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED" --debug --stacktrace` but it doesn't work.

Comment: It works if I put GRADLE_OPTS in .bashrc, then source it and run `gradle  --debug --stacktrace`

Comment: You have to pass it as a enviroment variable, usually it comes before the command in terminal.
GRADLE_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=256m" ./gradlew test

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16g wrapper
```

---

### NOTE

- Pay attention to `-D`, this marks the *property* to be passed to Gradle and JVM.
- Using `-P` a property is passed as Gradle *project property*.

Comment: Should you list all of your JVM args behind one parameter like this multiple ?

Comment: It depends on jvmArgs doc, more complex example: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms2g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx2g" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy="in-process"

Answer (score 0):

Hi for Intellij IDEA run you can add property to JM Options at Run Configuration.
First make sure you have enabled add VM options at Modify Options
[image]

After that add --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
to vm option

[image]

For deployment add options to gradle run as @ultraon described or for  Docker add to run_script.sh as JAVA_OPTS

JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+UseG1GC 
-Xms512m 
-Xmx2048m 
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dspring.profiles.active=$PROFILE,discovery"