# How to pass data provider thread count parameter from build.gradle to testng.xml

Tags: selenium, testing, gradle, automated-tests, testng

I am looking to pass data provider thread count value from command line an then pick this parameter in build.gradle and use it inside useTestNg() inside the test task. Is this possible?

For example:
Command: gradle clean build test -Pdataproviderthreadcount=5

Can this be captured using systemPropeties and the value to be used in useTestNg()

Answer (score 1):

Since dataproviderthreadcount is a VM option, I used this as below and it worked as expected. My project is a Cucumber, Gradle and testNG.

TEST_ENV=STG BROWSER=chrome ./gradlew clean build -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Ddataproviderthreadcount=2

You can also refer [How can I pass VM arguments to gradle from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930552/how-can-i-pass-vm-arguments-to-gradle-from-command-line)